# Reading XML and repeating a value across a cell range

Tags: excel, msxml, vba

I have the following xml that I would like to import into Excel using VBA

```
<rootElement xmlns:n0="http://www.w3.org/n0/" xmlns:n1="http://www.w3.org/n1/">
<n0:Partner>
    <n1:Identifier>EMH38</n1:Identifier>
    <n1:A>
        <n1:B>
            <n1:C>WZFR8</n1:C>
            <n1:D>Coll</n1:D>
            <n1:E>1</n1:E>
        </n1:B>
        <n1:B>
            <n1:C>X3HV7</n1:C>
            <n1:D>Coll</n1:D>
            <n1:E>2</n1:E>
        </n1:B>
        <n1:B>
            <n1:C>X5E86</n1:C>
            <n1:D>Coll</n1:D>
            <n1:E>3</n1:E>
        </n1:B>
        <n1:B>
            <n1:C>X5FC6</n1:C>
            <n1:D>Coll</n1:D>
        </n1:B>
        <n1:B>
            <n1:C>X5FL6</n1:C>
            <n1:D>Coll</n1:D>
            <n1:E>5</n1:E>
        </n1:B>
    </n1:A>
</n0:Partner>
```

After reading in the file, the output in the Excel worksheet was

```
 Identifier C       D       E
 EMH38      WZFR8      Coll     1
            X3HV7      Coll     2
            X5E86      Coll     3
            X5FC6      Coll 
            X5FL6      Coll     5
```

The preferred output after reading in the file would have to be the following. 
How can I make the Identifier appear on each row?

```
 Identifier C       D       E
 EMH38      WZFR8      Coll     1
 EMH38      X3HV7      Coll     2
 EMH38      X5E86      Coll     3
 EMH38      X5FC6      Coll 
 EMH38      X5FL6      Coll     5
```

Comment: You should post your code.So, we can think more and our solution will be effective for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, my approach for your problem.

```
Public Sub readXML()

    Dim xmlUrl As String
    Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim partner, elements, bNode, child  As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim row As Integer

    'Get xml file path
    xmlUrl = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\test.xml"

    xmlDoc.async = False

    'If loading xml file has no error
    If xmlDoc.Load(xmlUrl) Then

        'Set start row of sheet
        row = 1

        'Get root element from xml document
        Set elements = xmlDoc.DocumentElement

        'Loop all child tags from "n0:Partner" tags
        For Each partner In elements.ChildNodes

            'Loop all child tags from 'n1:A' tags
            For Each bNode In partner.ChildNodes(1).ChildNodes

                Sheets("sheetname").Range("A" & row) = partner.ChildNodes(0).Text

                'Loop all child tags from from 'n1:B' tags
                For Each child In bNode.ChildNodes

                    'Check node name and set value to cell
                    Select Case child.nodeName

                        Case "n1:C"
                            Sheets("sheetname").Range("C" & row) = child.Text

                        Case "n1:D"
                            Sheets("sheetname").Range("D" & row) = child.Text

                        Case "n1:E"
                            Sheets("sheetname").Range("E" & row) = child.Text

                    End Select

                Next child

                'Increase row
                row = row + 1

           Next bNode

        Next partner

    End If

End Sub
```